# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning Firestore with Java and tried the sample code provided by Firebase official site https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Its a very simple code

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials; import 
com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp; import 
com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

// Use a service account InputStream serviceAccount = new 
FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccount.json"); GoogleCredentials 
credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount); 
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder() 
.setCredentials(credentials) .build(); 
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

Here while getting db object, I am getting an error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ALPN is not configured properly. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting for more information.
at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1beta1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:138)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:71)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ALPN is not configured properly. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting for more information.
at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:163)
at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:136)
at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:124)
at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:94)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:546)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:539)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:477)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:325)
at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:342)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:185)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:142)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:134)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:129)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1beta1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:124)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured(JettyTlsUtil.java:34)
at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:153)
... 29 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My IDE is intellij where I am running this and org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN is visible in the classpath under External Libraries

```
alpn-api-1.1.3.v20160715.jar
ALPN
```

Has someone encountered a similar issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I generated my google service account key wrongly. I have followed through Firestore documentation and generated correct key

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Do you remember what was the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem in my FireStore project: `ALPN is not configured properly` >`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN`. Project was working OK few month ago and I was pretty much disappointed with that problem.

The message is quite misleading and is far from the root cause in my case. I was trying to run project with `Java x32` and `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` (used by `grpc`, used by firestore API) has implementation only for 'x64' (you may check supported natives in `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.8.Final.jar/META-INF/native/`). While debugging I discovered that `root cause` of the problem is silently suppressed and after failure to load 'x86 version of netty_tcnative_windows_*.dll' code tries to run using `ALPN`, but this needs additional customization of project startup.

So ... correct problem is - **Do not run Firestore project on Jdk x32**

Comment: That was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly my problem.